# How to attach a VM with a vnet to a public workspace in azure

Tags: azure, virtual, azure-virtual-machine

I have an azure vm with a vnet and when I attach this vm to the public workspace, I received timeout and Verify that server is accessible and SSH service is accepting connections.

```
Provisioning error
Connection attempt timed out for 'xx.xx.xx.xx'. Verify that server is accessible and SSH service is accepting connections.
```

Is it possible to do it? thanks

Comment: Could you please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-network-security-overview#public-workspace-and-secured-resources).

Comment: Private endpoint / private link is for service, can it apply to virtual machine too?

Comment: what is `public workspace`?

Comment: Hi @susanne, if the provided answer resolved your issue, you may mark it as answer or upvote it so that others who encounter the similar issue, it may be useful for them or community members.

Answer (score 1):

•   I would suggest you to please refer to the below documentation link wherein we consider that the **Azure webapp deployed as a prerequisite has a public IP address** and we are creating a **private endpoint from a VM to connect to the public URL of the webapp which is our public workspace**.

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-endpoint-portal?tabs=dynamic-ip***

Thus, when you create a private endpoint for a website or an app service as said in the document above, you select the ***private endpoint’s association with a private virtual network of your choice and an Azure resource which is authorized to access the publicly available workspace or web app from that private virtual network***. In this way, `publicly available workspace can be accessed securely from a private endpoint via a private IP enabled VM`.

•   `To ensure that the workspace is accessible from the VM`, try to **telnet the publicly available URL of the public workspace from the Azure VM** and check whether it is reachable. If not, then ***check the network security group of the VM as well as the IP restriction policies of the deployed web app/public workspace for any port blockage and restrictions**. Also, do **ensure that port 22 TCP for SSH is also enabled and allowed through a rule in the NSG of the deployed VM along with the high priority, otherwise rules defined with higher priorities will take effect over them and subdue their effect**.

Please do ensure that if an **application security group or a gateway or NVA (Network Virtual Appliance) like Firewall is configured in between your Azure environment and the public workspace**, then kindly **check for the TCP SSH port 22 and all other required connecting ports also for any UDRs or rules that might block the connection from your VM**.

Find the below snapshots for your reference: -

[image: Testapp-private endpoint]

[image: Private endpoint - 1]

[image: Private endpoint - 2]